# python url parsing 'function' object has no attribute 'urlparse'

Tags: python, string, parsing, url, scrapy

Trying to parse a url that I get with scrapy

```
def parse_info_has_id(self, css_path):
    profileID = ""
    for div in css_path.xpath('div'):
        url = "".join(div.css('div > a::attr(href)').extract())
        if "add_friend.php?id" in url:
            print(url)
            #parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
            #print urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['id']

    return profileID
```

This prints

```
/a/mobile/friends/add_friend.php?id=100003669247258&hf=search&sld=eyJzZWFyY2hfc2lkIjoiNGYxMmNhZGJhZDVkOGQ5ZGFkN2RkZTdhYjc3MTMwNTQiLCJxdWVyeSI6IjIwMjM2MDg3OTciLCJzZWFyY2hfdHlwZSI6IlNlYXJjaCIsInNlcXVlbmNlX2lkIjoxOTg2MTg0OTIzLCJwYWdlX251bWJlciI6MSwiZmlsdGVyX3R5cGUiOiJTZWFyY2giLCJlbnRfaWQiOjEwMDAwMzY2OTI0NzI1OCwicG9zaXRpb24iOjAsInJlc3VsdF90eXBlIjoyMDQ4fQ%3D%3D&gfid=AQB03j5V7CqqGQSD/graphsearch/100003669247258/photos-of?ent=100003669247258&refid=0&query=2023608797&sld=eyJzZWFyY2hfc2lkIjoiNGYxMmNhZGJhZDVkOGQ5ZGFkN2RkZTdhYjc3MTMwNTQiLCJxdWVyeSI6IjIwMjM2MDg3OTciLCJzZWFyY2hfdHlwZSI6IlNlYXJjaCIsInNlcXVlbmNlX2lkIjoxOTg2MTg0OTIzLCJwYWdlX251bWJlciI6MSwiZmlsdGVyX3R5cGUiOiJTZWFyY2giLCJlbnRfaWQiOjEwMDAwMzY2OTI0NzI1OCwicG9zaXRpb24iOjAsInJlc3VsdF90eXBlIjoyMDQ4fQ%3D%3D&source=pivot
```

I want to get the id = `100003669247258` from the string but when I try

```
#parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
#print urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['id']
```

I get `'function' object has no attribute 'urlparse'` error, how can I parse that url string to get either id from `add_friend.php?id=10000366924725` or `/graphsearch/100003669247258/`

Comment: What is the import statement?

Comment: `from urlparse import urljoin, parse_qs ,urlparse`

Comment: You should use the function urlparse itself as long as it was imported: parsed = urlparse(url). The same thing with parse_qs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to only get the id from the string, you can achieve it using `re`.

```
import re
match_object =  re.search("id=(\d+)", "/a/mobile/friends/add_friend.php?id=100003669247258&hf=search&sld=eyJzZWFyY2hfc2lkIjoiNGYxMmNhZGJhZDVkOGQ5ZGFkN2RkZTdhYjc3MTMwNTQiLCJxdWVyeSI6IjIwMjM2MDg3OTciLCJzZWFyY2hfdHlwZSI6IlNlYXJjaCIsInNlcXVlbmNlX2lkIjoxOTg2MTg0OTIzLCJwYWdlX251bWJlciI6MSwiZmlsdGVyX3R5cGUiOiJTZWFyY2giLCJlbnRfaWQiOjEwMDAwMzY2OTI0NzI1OCwicG9zaXRpb24iOjAsInJlc3VsdF90eXBlIjoyMDQ4fQ%3D%3D&gfid=AQB03j5V7CqqGQSD/graphsearch/100003669247258/photos-of?ent=100003669247258&refid=0&query=2023608797&sld=eyJzZWFyY2hfc2lkIjoiNGYxMmNhZGJhZDVkOGQ5ZGFkN2RkZTdhYjc3MTMwNTQiLCJxdWVyeSI6IjIwMjM2MDg3OTciLCJzZWFyY2hfdHlwZSI6IlNlYXJjaCIsInNlcXVlbmNlX2lkIjoxOTg2MTg0OTIzLCJwYWdlX251bWJlciI6MSwiZmlsdGVyX3R5cGUiOiJTZWFyY2giLCJlbnRfaWQiOjEwMDAwMzY2OTI0NzI1OCwicG9zaXRpb24iOjAsInJlc3VsdF90eXBlIjoyMDQ4fQ%3D%3D&source=pivot")
id = match_object.group(1)
print id
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

`import urllib.parse as urlparse`

Answer (score 3):

Import the library as:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

Use the method as:

```
urlparse(url)
```

Instead of:

```
urlparse.urlparse(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can import urlparse as:

`from urlparse import urlparse`

or you can also import from urllib as:

`from urllib import parse as urlparse`